# Java super set private fields

Tags: java

I'm learning java inheritance and encapsulation. Here is sample code

```
class Base {
  private int x;
  private int y;

  Base(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
  }

  public int getX() {
      return x;
  }

  public int getY() {
      return y;
  }
}

class Child extends Base {
  Child(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);
  }
}

Child c = new Child(1, 2);
System.out.println(c.getX());
```

Why have I access to `x` and `y` (private) in `Child` class? Does `super` change anything?

Comment: you don't have (direct) access to x and y, but you created `public` methods inside the Base class which are inherited by the Child class and thus make x and y accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have access to `x` and `y` in `Child` class. When you write

```
Child(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);
}
```

the `x` and `y` are formal parameters of `Child`'s constructor, that happen to be called the same names as private fields `x` and `y` of the superclass. They might as well be called something else - say, `a` and `b`, and the effect would be exactly the same:

```
Child(int a, int b) {
    super(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why have I access to x and y (private) in Child class?

you dont, if you would you could do without problem:

```
System.out.println(c.x);
System.out.println(c.y);
```

you wrote instead public setters/getters that are giving you access (capsulation) to the fields..